# Using Mediator Pattern with webpack and ES6 Modules import export

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, ecmascript-6, webpack, mediator

I have multiple widgets written and need to communicated between them. I am trying to use the mediator pattern to do that. So I have something like below. Problem I am having is mediator is 2 different instances instead of just 1. So widget_2 is not actually subscribing to correct event/message.

I am using WebPack/Es6

How can I overcome that?

```js
//mediator.js
    //ref: https://github.com/HenriqueLimas/mediator-pattern-es6/blob/master/src/mediator.js
    
    //app.js
    import Widget_1 from './widget_1.js';
    import Widget_2 from './widget_2.js';
    
    new widget_1 = new Widget_1();
    new widget_2 = new Widget_2();
    
    widget_1.run();
    widget_2.run();
    
    //widget_1.js
    import Mediator from './mediator.js';
    const mediator = new Mediator();
    
    export default class Widget_1 {
        constructor() {
            
        }
        run() {
            mediator.publish('widget1', 'hello there I am widget 1');
        }
    }
    
    //widget_2.js
    import Mediator from './mediator.js';
    const mediator = new Mediator();
    
    export default class Widget_2 {
        constructor() {
            
        }
        run() {
            mediator.subscribe('widget1', function(message) {
                console.log('widget 1 says:' + message);
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Make the mediator an argument of the `constructor` or the `run` method, instantiate it in your `app.js` and pass it to each instance.

Comment: Or modify your mediator using a Singleton pattern

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you make your mediator a singleton - the same object will by definition be shared anywhere you use it. This modification could look smth like this.

```
'use strict';

class Mediator {
    constructor() {
        this.channels = {};
    }

    subscribe(channel, fn) {
        if (!this.channels[channel]) this.channels[channel] = [];

        this.channels[channel].push({
            context: this,
            callback: fn
        });
    }

    publish(channel) {
        if (!this.channels[channel]) return false;

        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);

        this.channels[channel].forEach(function(subscription) {
            subscription.callback.apply(subscription.context, args);
        });

        return this;
    }

    installTo(obj) {
        obj.channels = {};

        obj.publish = this.publish;
        obj.subscribe = this.subscribe;
    }
}

var mediator = new Mediator();
export mediator;
```

But then you don't really need a es6 class here, as you will be using it only once to create a new object.